# Hardware and OS influence on Maven build speed

Tags: java, maven

Our 100+ Java developers are going to get new machines with Windows 10.

Currently we are trying to figure out how to make Maven builds faster. We already noticed that virus scan slows down the build by a factor of more than 2.

I guess that SSD speed is crucial, but our Benchmarks and the Maven build times correlate poorly.

What are other things that could have a noticeable impact on build speed?

Comment: RAM speed/amount, CPU speed, what other software is running....there's many variables, if you want the most speed you have to make sure your machine is unhindered.

Comment: My guess would be that CPU speed is not very important because copying and packing files is a large part of Maven builds. But it would be great if somebody has some data about this.

Comment: The most important things is IO speed which means very fast hard drives and network connections for upload/download of artifacts from/to repository manager ...things like SSD is really a thing which improves the speed. Furthermore the question is: Is really Maven the issue or tests? Have you measured the timing? And yes virus scans are also an issue..Apart from that is it really necessary to build on Windows (which is the worst case)?

Comment: @khmarbaise Most builds are not running (many) tests. Developers often build (large) ears to test them locally, and the desktop OS is Windows.

Comment: Could I expect a reasonable speedup when I run a build on Linux instead of Windows?

Comment: @khmarbaise Just curious, why is Windows the worst case?